# Crystal Reports - TestConnectivity returns true on dev machine but false on test machine

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports, report

I have a SQLServer 2005 database on a client server. I have a VPN connection to their server. I am using the connection code from here

When I run the winforms app from my local dev machine it works fine, reports display things are great. When I run the app from testing machine it fails. I have followed the trail and found out that it fails on the TestConnectivity method. This occurs despite the fact that I haven't changed anything in the code.

I am using the same VPN information, and I know that I can access the database from that machine. The clients also have trouble with it and they are on the same network.

I am using Windows XP SP3 for both PC's

Does anyone have any idea's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not have the SQLServer native client installed on the test machine but it was installed on my dev machine (due to SQLServer being installed).